# Storing user input and calculating for personality quiz in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, points

New to JS! So I have my basic html set up with 10 questions and started a bit on an array but I just need some clarification on what i should be doing.  I have values assigned to each answer corresponding with the appropriate result (out of 4).

The array I set up was just to help me visualize, I'm not sure which values to put in there as they correspond to the questions.  That's my first question.

My second is do I create another array to store user input?  And what attribute do I use to have JS calculate the points and give an appropriate result?

Here's my code so far (I only put 2 out of the ten questions since the rest are pretty much the same format)

```
<script>


// Questions and answers
var data ['Question 1','A','B','C','D',
      'Question 2','A','B','C','D',
      'Question 3','A','B','C','D',
      'Question 4','A','B','C','D',
      'Question 5','A','B','C','D',
      'Question 6','A','B','C','D',
      'Question 7','A','B','C','D',
      'Question 8'',A','B','C','D',
      'Question 9','A','B','C','D',
      'Question 10','A','B','C','D',]




</script>
</head>

<body>

<p id="quiz"></p>


<b id="one">1) Which lifestyle do you prefer?<br></b>

<p>
<p>
<label>
   <input id="firstone" type='radio' name="one" value="1" />
    Grounded, studious
</label>
<p>
<p>
<label>
  <input id="firsttwo" type='radio' name="one" value="2" />
    Relaxed, in control
 </label>
<p>
<p> 
<label>
   <input id="firstthree" type='radio' name="one" value="3" />
    Motivated, confident
</label>
<p>
<p>
<label>
  <input id="firstfour" type='radio' name="one" value="4" />
    Ambitious, carefree
</label>

<p>
<p>  

<b id="two">2) What kind of setting sounds ideal to live in?<br></b>

<p>
<p>
<label>
   <input id="secondone" type='radio' name="two" value="4" />
    Mountain tops
</label>
<p>
<p>
<label>
  <input id="secondtwo" type='radio' name="two" value="1" />
    Rocky Valley
 </label>
<p>
<p> 
<label>
   <input id="secondthree" type='radio' name="two" value="2" />
    Near bodies of water
</label>
<p>
<p>
<label>
  <input id="secondfour" type='radio' name="two" value="3" />
    Level ground
</label>

<p>
<p>
```

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/s7cp53t1/1/) might help you in learning JS ,creating dynamic question and answers and getting the selected answers. If this helped you i'll post it as answer @Jclee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to JS! It's definitely a fun language to learn and you can get quite a bit out of it.

So first off, the approach you're taking may be more complicated than it needs to be.

What you can do to simplify things is to wrap the questions in a `<form>` tag which can be referenced by the JS later. For example, taking a look at question 1 and 2, you could write:

```
<form id="questions">
    <b id="one">1) Which lifestyle do you prefer?</b>
    <fieldset id="q1">
        <input type="radio" value="a" name="q1"> Grounded, studious<br>
        <input type="radio" value="b" name="q1"> Relaxed, in control<br>
        <input type="radio" value="c" name="q1"> Motivated, confident<br>
        <input type="radio" value="d" name="q1"> Ambitious, carefree
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <b id="two">2) What kind of setting sounds ideal to live in?<br></b>            
    <fieldset id="q2">
        <input type="radio" value="a" name="q2"> Mountain tops<br>
        <input type="radio" value="b" name="q2"> Rocky Valley<br>
        <input type="radio" value="c" name="q2"> Near bodies of water<br>
        <input type="radio" value="d" name="q2"> Level ground<br>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

After that, you'd want to add a submit event handler that will grab each of the resulting values entered in each question, store them in an array, and calculate as needed from there. Here's a quick snippet to get the idea:

```
$( "form#questions" ).submit(function(e) {

  // This simply stops the form from submitting so you can grab data
  e.preventDefault(); 

  // Grab the values of each fieldset of radio buttons
  var a1 = document.getElementById('q1').value; // ... or some variation of this
  // Store in array or however you wish to handle it

  // Do some calculations with stored variables / array

});
```

I'm not entirely sure of the logic behind your questionnaire (i.e. how it computes the results), but I hope that this will at least give you a little better understanding of how you can accomplish it or in which direction you can go.

Also, as an additional note, take a look at [JavaScript Objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) to learn about JavaScript objects, they can be extremely useful in some cases where arrays wouldn't work.

Comment: This is extremely helpful! I just need to study it for a bit.  I'm just doing whichever value that the user selects the most, the result that corresponds with that value will show at the end.  Out of some research I'm guessing if else loops will help in calculating that?  Just need to study those now ><

Comment: Yup! The best way to learn JS is to just play around with it and look up documentation. If you are just grabbing the value the user selects the most, I'd recommend storing all the values in an array and then simply just counting the occurrences of each and determining which has the most. I slightly updated the first code snippet to have the values use a, b, c, and d instead of q1a, q1b, etc so you can count occurrences easier